# Apache Camel 2.18.1 http4 component throwing org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException when throwExceptionOnFailure=false

Tags: apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Camel 2.18.1 route which uses the http4 component and occasionally the component is throwing an org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException event when I have set throwExceptionOnFailure=false in the uri options.

According to the documentation:-

> If throwExceptionOnFailure=false the HttpOperationFailedException will
>   not be thrown for failed response codes. This allows you to get any
>   response from the remote server

I am setting up the http call using:-

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://www.therealurl.com"))
.to("http4://dummyhost?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
```

in the Java DSL which works fine for all the other options I set for proxies etc.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace. Also try with newer version.

Answer (score 0):

try enclosing your url in recipient list, for example in spring DSL

```
<camel:recipientList>
<camel:simple>http4://dummyhost?throwExceptionOnFailure=false</camel:simple>
</camel:recipientList>
```

Comment: Interesting, the URI for http4 is fixed so shouldn't need recipient lists' dynamic features. I'll give it a try.